# How can I stop SKSpriteNodes from moving when you click them once

Tags: swift, xcode, skspritenode

I've made a player sprite in gamescene.swift and a grid for the player to move on, and to move the player I've made up, down, left, and right buttons. I've made the button's positions relative to the player, because I'm using camera node, but for some reason they start closer to the player when the game starts, but when you click one of them they move to their proper positions and stay there. In both positions they function, but they change the first time you click them. Here's my code for the buttons inside a class but not a function

```
func addUpArrow() {
        upArrow.position = CGPoint(x: player.position.x + 950, y: player.position.y + -370)
        upArrow.name = "upArrow"
        upArrow.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        addChild(upArrow)
    }

    func addDownArrow() {
        downArrow.position = CGPoint(x: upArrow.position.x, y: upArrow.position.y - 100)
        downArrow.name = "downArrow"
        downArrow.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        addChild(downArrow)
    }

    func addLeftArrow() {
        leftArrow.position = CGPoint(x: upArrow.position.x - 50, y: upArrow.position.y - 50)
        leftArrow.name = "leftArrow"
        leftArrow.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        addChild(leftArrow)
    }

    func addRightArrow() {
        rightArrow.position = CGPoint(x: upArrow.position.x + 50, y: upArrow.position.y - 50)
        rightArrow.name = "rightArrow"
        rightArrow.size = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        addChild(rightArrow)
    }
```

And then inside the didMove function I call the functions to add the buttons, and to make sure they stay relative to the player, every time you click one of them, it removes them and replaces them with new ones, like this

```
 for node in touchedNode {
                if node.name == "upArrow" {
                    moveUp()
                    removeDirectionalButtons()
                    addDirectionButtons()
                }
                if node.name == "leftArrow" {
                    moveLeft()
                    removeDirectionalButtons()
                    addDirectionButtons()
                }
                if node.name == "rightArrow" {
                    moveRight()
                    removeDirectionalButtons()
                    addDirectionButtons()
                }
                if node.name == "downArrow" {
                    moveDown()
                    removeDirectionalButtons()
                    addDirectionButtons()
                }
            }
```

This isn't a major problem, but since I'm planning to eventually turn this into a real game, it would be best if this was fixed, but I can't figure out what I did
wrong. I have some screenshots of the simulator, here is right when you load the game
[image]

And this is after you click
[image]

I know this a minor problem, but it just doesn't look right or professional, so I'd like to fix it, but I don't know how to.

Edit: Now that I've added boundaries to the game, every time the player hits the boundary the controls move back to when the game loads, and it keeps shifting back and forth now.